# Building a datetime in a form_for without using datetime_select in rails, how to send params

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, form-for

I've searched everywhere and I think the solution is easy but I'm overcomplicating it.

Basically I have an Appointment model that has the following attributes:

```
--- !ruby/object:Appointment
attributes:
  id: 
  time: 
  user_id: 
  created_at: 
  updated_at:
```

**time: is a datetime attribute**

In the controller I have a standard create action:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
     @appointment = Appointment.create(appointment_params)
     current_user.appointment = @appointment

     if @appointment.save
       flash[:success] = "Appointment Booked!"
       redirect_to appointments_path
     else
       redirect_to appointments_path
     end

  private
    def appointment_params
      params.require(:appointment).permit(:time, :test1, :test2)
    end
  end
```

And in the create view I have a form for with the following code:

```
<%= form_for(@appointment) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select(:time, {start_year: 2015, end_year: 2016, start_hour: 9, end_hour: 18, minute_step: 60}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now this all saves absolutely fine and does what I want, a user creates an appointment with the datetime selector and it gets saved no problems.

**However**, when it comes to styling this it becomes difficult as I dont know how to break up the datetime_select.

What I want to do is use a jQuery datetime picker I found, but I have no clue how I will pass through the params to my controller in order to build a datetime to be able to save to the **time:** attribute

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem, do you want delete the default calendar and use JQuery calendar?

Comment: Hey, sorry if this question confused you! Basically I want to learn how to build up a datetime without using the datetime_select helper in rails.

Comment: Are you using formtastic or similar?

Comment: No as you can see in the code im just using the form_for helper

Answer (score 0):

There're many ways to do that, one of this is using a simple f.textbox, and use JQuery datepicker on this inputs.

A more profesional way is overwriting datetime_select.

***An example:***

create a **DatePickerInput** class in app/inputs

```
module SimpleForm
  module Inputs
    class DateTimePickerInput < Base
      def input
        @builder.text_field(attribute_name,input_html_options)
      end    
    end
  end
end
```

Use this  `$("input.date_time_picker").datepicker();` for create a JQuery Datepicker

For using that `<%= f.input :deadline, :as => :date_time_picker %>`